# Using std::chrono / date::gps_clock for converting a double gps timestamp to utc/tai

Tags: c++, date, gps, utc, c++-chrono

I get a timestamp from a GPS device in a gps_data struct as a double.

I'd like to convert this GPS timestamp to UTC and TAI times, something simple as:

```
void handle_gps_timestamp(double timestamp) 
{
    double utc = utc_from_gps(timestamp);
    double tai = tai_from_gps(timestamp);
    do_stuff(gps, utc, tai);
}
```

Luckily I found [Howard Hinnant's date and timezone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/) (proposed for C++20) that seems to provide this exact functionality. Unfortunately, at least from what I can see, the date/tz/chrono library has no convenient methods that allow this simple usage.

I must first somehow "transfer" my double into a known chrono/date type. But OK, since I understand the overall concept, namely that the ***timepoint*** is defined as a ***duration*** after (or before) the ***epoch*** of a ***clock***, and I think that this is a beautiful model.

**Assumption**

I should be able to very easily translate that model to fit my problem, right?

In my case, I have a timestamp that is a point in time, specified as the duration since the gps epoch. Now, there should be a class type of a clock that abstracts and handles all of this for me, I'd like to think. And yes! There is a date::gps_clock and a date::gps_time, which surely should do the work.

**Problem**

I cannot make it work for me. I'm sure the solution is trivial.

**Question**

Can someone give me a helping hand, showing how I should use Howard's date library applied to my problem?

Comment: May you include what have you tried so far?

Comment: What units does your `double` represent?  Seconds since the epoch?

Comment: Yes, sorry, seconds since epoch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is difficult to answer this question precisely because the input to the problem is underspecified:

> I get a timestamp from a GPS device in a gps_data struct as a double ... specified as the duration since the gps epoch.

Therefore I'm going to make some assumptions.  I'll state all of my assumptions, and hopefully it will be clear how to alter my answer for other guesses/facts about what that `double` represents.

Let's say that the `double` is a non-integral count of milliseconds since the gps epoch.  Let's furthermore assume that I want to capture the precision of this input down to microseconds.

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    double gps_input = 1e+12 + 1e-3;
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using dms = duration<double, std::milli>;
    gps_time<microseconds> gt{round<microseconds>(dms{gps_input})};
    auto utc = clock_cast<utc_clock>(gt);
    auto tai = clock_cast<tai_clock>(gt);
    std::cout << gt << " GPS\n";
    std::cout << utc << " UTC\n";
    std::cout << tai << " TAI\n";
}
```

I've arbitrarily created an example input and stored it in `gps_input`.

Some using directives make the code a lot less verbose.

A custom `chrono::duration` type that *exactly* matches the documented specification for what the `double` represents makes things *much* simpler, and lessens the chance for errors.  In this case I've made a `chrono::duration` that stores `milliseconds` in a `double` and named that type `dms`.

Now you simply convert the `double` to `dms`, and then using `round`, convert the `dms` to `microseconds`, and store those `microseconds` in a gps time point with precision `microseconds` or finer.  One could use `duration_cast` in place of `round`, but when converting from floating point to integral, I usually prefer `round`, which means round-to-nearest-and-to-even-on-tie.

Now that you have a `gps_time`, one can use the `clock_cast` function to convert to other times such as `utc_time` and `tai_time`.

This program outputs:

```
2011-09-14 01:46:40.000001 GPS
2011-09-14 01:46:25.000001 UTC
2011-09-14 01:46:59.000001 TAI
```

Adjust the `milliseconds` and `microseconds` units above as needed.  For example if the input represents `seconds`, the easiest thing to do is to default the second template argument on `dms`:

```
using dms = duration<double>;
```

[This library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/) works with C++11/14/17.  And with minor modifications it is now part of the official C++20 specification.

Comment: Thank you very much Howard for such a descriptive and informative answer!

Comment: I guess I’m not comfortable enough with this round- and cast-conventions, making this library a little bit awkward for me to use in the beginning.

Comment: These are `std::chrono` concepts.  Perhaps this video tutorial about `chrono` would help?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: And to complete the example, since I wanted the output in double:     auto dur = utc.time_since_epoch();
    auto duration_in_seconds = std::chrono::duration<double>(dur);
    double num_seconds = duration_in_seconds.count();

Comment: the above example no longer compiles, could you please fix this?

Comment: I'd be happy to.  I just compiled it on macOS under `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14` and `-std=c++17` without any errors.  What are you seeing, and on what platform and flags?

Answer (score -2):

The other answer isn't bad but it does require you to have c++17, curl, run cmake, and acquire some custom libraries.

Something that is much easier to drop in as a .h and .cpp would be http://www.leapsecond.com/tools/gpsdate.c.

That doesn't handle the TAI conversion but that might also be on that list.