# How to convert gps time to utc in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, gps, utc, data-conversion

I am collecting GPS time (in ns) from a sensor and I am looking for a way to convert that to a UTC time in C++.

I have a working code before in python.

```
    time_gps = time_gps * 10**(-9)    # Converts ns -> s
    gps_epoch = pd.datetime(year=1980, month=1, day=6)
    delta = pd.to_timedelta(time_gps, unit='s')
    time = gps_epoch + delta - pd.to_timedelta(19, unit='s')
```

Using the link "[Using std::chrono / date::gps_clock for converting a double gps timestamp to utc/tai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452157/using-stdchrono-dategps-clock-for-converting-a-double-gps-timestamp-to-utc)" helped me figure out how to convert from GPS time to UTC.

```
    uint64_t gps_input_ns = 1281798087485516800;         
    date::gps_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds> gt_nano{date::round<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::nano>{gps_input_ns})};
    auto utc_nano = date::clock_cast<date::utc_clock>(gt_nano);
    std::cout << utc_nano << " UTC\n";
```

```
Output: 2020-08-18 15:01:09.485516800 UTC
```

My next question is, how can I extract the date and time from the variable "utc_nano"? I'm not very familiar with chrono or the date library and therefore having problems trying to separate the date and time. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note a duplicate, but informative: [Using std::chrono / date::gps_clock for converting a double gps timestamp to utc/tai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452157/using-stdchrono-dategps-clock-for-converting-a-double-gps-timestamp-to-utc). On second thought, could be a duplicate if you chose to go the `chrono` route.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "get"?  Is the result you want in terms of output on the terminal, or a string?  Or do you want chrono types that represent the date and time separately?  In other words, is this a formatting question or a data structure question?

Comment: @HowardHinnant I edited my question to be a little more specific hoping that it will answer your questions. What I mean by "get" is to extract the date and time from the variable "utc_nano".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that leap seconds are important to you since you're dealing with gps time which represents the physical seconds that are labeled leap seconds by UTC.  It is fairly tricky to manipulate date/times with leaps seconds, which is why [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is so popular in computer systems.

In the [C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is modeled by `sys_time`, whereas true UTC is modeled by `utc_time`.  The only difference between these two models is that `sys_time` doesn't count leap seconds and `utc_time` does.

The advantage of `sys_time` is that there exists a fast and efficient algorithm for translating the time duration since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 into fields:  year, month, day, hour, minute, second, subseconds.  So if you want to break `utc_time` into these fields, the trick is to first turn `utc_time` into `sys_time`, while remembering whether or not your `utc_time` is referencing a leap second.  Indeed, this is exactly what the streaming operator for `utc_time` does.

There exists a helper function [`get_leap_second_info`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.utc.nonmembers) to aid in doing this.  This function takes a `utc_time` and returns a `{is leap second, count of leap seconds}` struct.  The first member is true if the argument refers to a leap second, the second argument tells you how many leap seconds there have been between the argument and 1970.  So the first step is to get this information for `utc_nano`:

```
auto info = get_leap_second_info(utc_nano);
```

Now you can create a `sys_time` with this information.  Since `sys_time` is just like `utc_time` excluding leap seconds, you can just subtract off the number of leap seconds that have occurred:

```
sys_time<nanoseconds> sys_nano{utc_nano.time_since_epoch() - info.elapsed};
```

Now you have a count of nanoseconds in [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  Truncating to `days` precision gives you a count of days in [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

```
auto sys_day = floor<days>(sys_nano);
```

`sys_day` is a date.  The time of day is simply the difference between the nanoseconds-precision time_point and the days-precision time_point:

```
auto tod = sys_nano - sys_day;
```

`tod` is a time.  It is the duration since midnight.  It may be short by a second.  That information is in `info.is_leap_second`.

If you want these types as "field types", you could convert `sys_day` to type `year_month_day`:

```
year_month_day ymd = sys_days;
```

`year_month_day` has getters for `year`, `month` and `day`.

You can convert `tod` into a `{hours, minutes, seconds, nanoseconds}` struct with:

```
hh_mm_ss hms{tod};
```

This has getters:  `hours()`, `minutes()`, `seconds()`, and `subseconds()`.  The above syntax assumes C++17.  If in C++11 or 14, the syntax is:

```
hh_mm_ss<nanoseconds> hms{tod};
```

`hh_mm_ss` doesn't directly support a count of 60s, but that information is still in `info.is_leap_second`.  E.g.

```
std::cout << hms.seconds().count() + info.is_leap_second << '\n';
```

That will output 60 if and only if `info.is_leap_second` is true.

Comment: Thank you for the help! So my approach is different but has similar steps. 

- I got sys_time by using clock_cast: 
`auto utc_sys = clock_cast<system_clock>(utc_nano)`.
- Then I got sys_days by using 
`auto utc_dp = date::floor<date::days>(utc_sys)`.
- To get the date, I used year_month_day:
`auto ymd = year_month_day{utc_dp}`
- and for the time I used make_time: 
`auto time = make_timeduration_cast<nanoseconds>(utc_sys-utc_dp))`.
- Then I used the getters you have mentioned to format my date and time.

Comment: That works except during a leap second.  If you start with a GPS time that is during a leap second, the `clock_cast` to `sys_time` will land on the last representable instant prior to the leap second.  So the date will be correct, and the time will be 23:59:59.999...

Answer (score 1):

You can even try this code which makes use of C time related functions

```
uint64_t ns = 1281798087485516800ULL + 315964800000000000ULL; // offset between gps epoch and unix epoch is 315964800 seconds

struct timespec ts;
ts.tv_sec = ns / 1000000000ULL;
ts.tv_nsec = ns % 1000000000ULL;

struct tm stm;
gmtime_r(&ts.tv_sec, &stm);
std::cout << stm.tm_year + 1900 << "-" << stm.tm_mon + 1 << "-" << stm.tm_mday << " " << stm.tm_hour << ":" << stm.tm_min << ":" << stm.tm_sec << std::endl;
```